# need to modify table structure in the below described format in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data.tables in below formats

```
1. 1314 obs. of 1 var

col1
1
2
3
4
5....
1314

2. 65700 obs. of 1 var
col2
1
2
3
4
5......
65700
```

I want to create a single table with the below format

```
col1   col2
1      1
       2
       3..
       50
2      51
       52
       53..
       100
.      .
.      .
.      .
1314   65650
       65651..
       65700
```

It might be a noobish question, but a quick help is very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: How is col1 mapped to col2?

Comment: Hello @avi, did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [`rep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html) function to do the work:

```
d1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:1314)  # 1314 obs. of 1 var
d2 <- data.frame(col2 = 1:65700) # 65700 obs. of 1 var

data.frame(col1 = rep(d1$col1, each = 50),
           col2 = d2$col2)

#   col1 col2
# 1    1    1
# 2    1    2
# 3    1    3
# 4    1    4
# 5    1    5
# 6    1    6
# ...
# 65695 1314 65695
# 65696 1314 65696
# 65697 1314 65697
# 65698 1314 65698
# 65699 1314 65699
# 65700 1314 65700
```